# Key points for designing secured admin section of a JSF 2.0 website

Tags: jsf-2

I want to know the key points, which one should keep in mind while designing the secured administrator section of an website in JSF2.0. This question is also about security measures. I have two doubt also.

1. If the same css file is used by both public section and secured admin section, should
   we separate it by keeping same css in two places, one for public section
   another one for secured admin section?
2. `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:graphicImage>`, etc always consider the
   path relative to `/resources` root folder. So how to assignin path to
   all those css, images, etc files, which are used by secured admin section? Because
   using `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:graphicImage>`, etc might reveal the
   path for secured admin section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If the same css file is used by both public section and secured admin section, should   we separate it by keeping same css in two places, one for public section another one for secured admin section?*

I don't see why that's necessary. If the admin section requires additional style classes then it would make sense to create an additional stylesheet file next to the existing stylesheet file for the public section. It does not improve security, but it does improve performance as the public section visitor won't get unnecessary CSS declarations.

---

> *`<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:graphicImage>`, etc always consider the path relative to `/resources` root folder. So how to assignin path to all those css, images, etc files, which are used by secured admin section? Because using `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:graphicImage>`, etc might reveal the path for secured admin section.*

I don't see how that would be a problem. You have of course secured the admin section with a solid login check. The resources which are going to be used by the admin section would not contain sensitive information like names/passwords at all. You can however always put those resources in a common subfolder of `/resources` folder and put the very same login check on it.

Comment: So, Can I put all the resources (without bothering about the admin section) under /resources directory?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you want a login check on certain resources, just put them in a common subfolder on which you then add to URLs to be checked for authentication/authorization like as you already did for the admin section.